# Is it possible to confirm the identity of a bot via HTTP request headers?

Tags: azure, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I'm looking to proxy requests to https://directline.botframework.com for specific consumers but only allow them to use the proxy for a specific bot:

consumers -> my.proxy.com -> directline.botframework.com

I read in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46700094/1577868) *"the Direct Line secret or token that you specify in the Authorization header of the request is used to identify the bot that the request should be directed to"*

I'm unable to find any documentation on the syntax of tokens but examples  appear to follow a certain pattern of 11 chars followed by period...:

```
Authorization: Bearer RCurR_XV9ZA.cwA.BKA.iaJrC8xpy8qbOF5xnR2vtCX7CZj0LdjAPGfiCpg4Fv0y8qbOF5xPGfiCpg4Fv0y8qqbOF5x8qbOF5xn
```

Are any of these fields(?), e.g. first 11 characters before first period, a unique identifier for a bot that I could use to filter requests on?

Comment: As you said, it seems that no any documentation demonstrates how to extract information of bot from a Direct Line secret or token to identify the bot. If possible, you can try to create a [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues) to report it.

Comment: Thanks @FeiHan, I'll create that now. I've also raised a support ticket via the Azure portal so will update with any feedback.

Comment: "only allow them to use the proxy for a specific bot": do you already know the secret for this specific bot?

Comment: @NicolasR, yes. We only want to be able to proxy requests to bots we have created and have control over.

Comment: If your consumers are using the secret directly, can't you just store a list of those secrets and check the Bearer value?

Comment: I don't believe the tokens/secrets are static in our implementation but I will check. I (probably wrongly) assumed at least part of the bearer value would change with each session/conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you decode the bearer token you can get the app id. I just tested this with [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) and was able to see my correct app id.

[image]

You can probably find a library that you can use to do this for you to get the app id, but I do not know one off hand. If you have access to the whole request another option would be to parse the activity for the bot id ( in c# `activity.recipient.id` or `activity.from.id` depending on direction) and use this data to whitelist somehow. This is a fairly unique case so I do not have any examples of this.